# VB.net Cannot Add Gmap Control to Form

Tags: vb.net

I Use VS2012 and Want Use Maps With [GMap](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/downloads/get/67818)
But when i want add GmapControl to form see this error:

[Error http://www.angrypic.ir/image.php?id=1FDE_509B9A2C](http://www.angrypic.ir/image.php?id=1FDE_509B9A2C)